# Problem running automated Tests using TFS, in correct order

Tags: selenium, tfs, automation

I am using the TFS Web Portal to create test suites for automated testing and from Visual Studio test project, I can associate any [Test Method] to any TFS Test case. The tests can then be run from TFS.

As you can see below, my test suite has some setup tests then some actual tests. I have a Test Method that sets a folder where my test suite will then crop it's screenshots, I then Launch the application I am going to test and login. I then do a test, set the screenshot prefix to the requirement number 1581 (as that's the requirement tested) and I repeat this for requirement 2062 then 2061.

The problem is that these tests run in the wrong order.

I know about Ordered Tests and I know I could simply put all of this in an ordered test and run it. In fact I used ordered tests, myself and 1 other tester in the team has a Visual Studio installation and the skills to use ordered tests. The requirement from the rest of the team (manual testers and managers) is that I need to split my tests up (as shown below).

As I created the test suite below, I thought it all worked. I can run the first 5 tests. Inspired by this I added the last 4 tests in my 9 test suite. It all started to fail though!

[image: TFS Test Suite (Web Portal) - 5 tests work!]

Now when I run all 9 tests, the 4th test (that had worked fine) fails as it is somehow run in the wrong order by TFS. I know this because my tests all create 1 or more screenshots. These screenshots work but are being created in the wrong order.

[image: One of the tests has now failed!]

I know a lot of people will tell me to use Ordered Tests and they will tell me that each test should be self contained. The reason I am deviating from that is that I have 4 thousand tests that verify 3 thousand requirements. If I want to test that a member record can have attributes X, Y and Z then that is 3 requirements. I want 1 setup test (launch the application, login, create a basic record). Then I want 1 test that X works, 1 test that Y works and 1 test that Z works. I have 3 requirements so I need at least 3 tests. If each test repeats all of the setup (Launch the app, login and create a basic record) then my test suite will take forever to run and will quickly become too slow.

I also want these to be split up because manual testers with no programming skills and no visual studio experience will be expected to look at my test suites, find the failed tests and re-test manually. If my tests suites all have 1 test in TFS, they will not know what went wrong. If I have 9 tests in a test suite and 1 fails, they will know what to manually re-test.

Finally, I have seen similar question relating to Microsoft Test Manager. This is not a duplicate question, MTM is not supported anymore so I'm using the Web Portal (as pictured). I have also seen this question relating to Visual Studio 2010 etc. I am using Visual Studio 2019 so it's not a duplicate, VS has changed a lot.

Comment: *If each test repeats all of the setup (Launch the app, login and create a basic record) then my test suite will take forever to run and will quickly become too slow.* Yes, that is a fundamental problem with UI testing, which is one of the many reasons why the industry has been moving away from having large suites of UI tests for over a decade.

Comment: Daniel Mann, yes I agree. I have about 50 tests that I've written (and executed) from Visual Studio. I simply want to have these tests run from TFS in order to pass the tests (and therefore the linked requirements). I really want to do this without closing the application and launching it and logging in and setting up a test between each test. This was ok in VS. Just hoping TFS can do similar.